# List not showing up on making REST call

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest

I have a custom list that I am trying to get contents from a designer workflow. I am testing the link on the browser, but the list does not show up and instead throws "page not found" error when I try to access it using the _vti_bin url format:

```
MySite/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ListName/
```

However if I use the _api/web url format then it shows up:

```
MySite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items
```

What could be causing this problem?
There is a another very simple test list that I created and it is pulling up through both urls fine. Why is this inconsistency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inconsistency. There might be a space somewhere that is breaking your HTTP request. Can you make sure that the **ListName** bit has no spaces in it? If you are using the **Workflow Context: List Name**, then this probably has spaces in it.

If you have a list called "**My List**" this is how your calls should look like:

- `MySite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('My List')`
- `MySite/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MyList`

You can see that the second version has no space in the list title.

---

**NOTE** that you can use the Fiddler or Postman (a web browser like Google Chrome is good too) to access and test those URLs before you use them in workflows. I actually highly recommend you test your calls to the SharePoint RESTful web services using one of these tools.

Comment: wow! just wow! Working now when I dropped the space. I was encoding it with %20 for no reason. I didn't know it removes the spaces. Thank you very much!

Comment: Tip: Don't learn/use (oldskool) SOAP unless you really have to, Stick with REST and your skills will be way more future proof.